# Will a SELECT . . . INTO use short-circuit evaluation for a COALESCE?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I'm building a stored proc that can take in two separate values that each can be used to identify a single record. One of these values may be null.

My logic is as follows: if `IN_ORDER_ID` is not NULL, save it to `V_ORDER_ID`. If it is NULL, then retrieve `ORDER_ID` with a query and save that to `V_ORDER_ID`. `V_ORDER_ID` is then used in the rest of the procedure.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT COALESCE(IN_ORDER_ID, order_id) INTO V_ORDER_ID FROM SCHEMA.ORDER WHERE SXC_ORDER_NUMBER = IN_SXC_ORDER_NUMBER;
```

My Question: Will the coalesce in this query still take advantage of [short-circuit evaluation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm)?

Comment: What do you expect from short circuit evaluation in this case? Are you hoping that the `FROM SCHEMA.ORDER WHERE SXC_ORDER_NUMBER = IN_SXC_ORDER_NUMBER;` will only be evaluated if `IN_ORDER_ID` is not null? If so I doubt that will be the case because the semantics of the query is that it needs to find any rows that match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you ask is:

> "Will the coalesce in this query still take advantage of short-circuit
>   evaluation?"

Within the context of the `COALESCE` expression, the answer to this is **yes**. Oracle will evaluate `IN_ORDER_ID`, and if it is not null, does not need to evaluate the column value of order_id.

However, I believe the question you intend to ask is:

> "Will short-circuit evaluation mean the statement does not have to access the
>   `SCHEMA.ORDER` table?"

Then the answer is ***ABSOLUTELY NOT***.

Table access must occur to evaluate the WHERE clause to identify how many rows to return. For example, if `IN_ORDER_ID` is not null, but no rows match on `SXC_ORDER_NUMBER = IN_SXC_ORDER_NUMBER`, then no rows will be returned by the query, and `V_ORDER_ID` will be `NULL`.

Consider the behavior from this version of your query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(IN_ORDER_ID, order_id) INTO V_ORDER_ID 
FROM SCHEMA.ORDER 
WHERE 1=2; --Where no rows match
--
SELECT V_ORDER_ID FROM dual;
```

Is this the intended behavior when no rows match the `WHERE` clause?

A different approach, with different behavior would be to use an approach like @SlimsGhost used in [his answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145644/will-a-select-into-use-short-circuit-evaluation-for-a-coalesce/145687#145687), or to use `IF`control flow to do variable assignment:

```
IF IN_ORDER_ID IS NOT NULL
    THEN V_ORDER_IF := IN_ORDER_ID;
ELSE
    SELECT order_id INTO V_ORDER_ID 
    FROM SCHEMA.ORDER 
    WHERE SXC_ORDER_NUMBER = IN_SXC_ORDER_NUMBER;
ENDIF;
--
SELECT V_ORDER_ID FROM dual;
```

These alternate approaches avoid accessing `SCHEMA.ORDER` if `IN_ORDER_ID` is not null. As a result, the `V_ORDER_ID` assignment happens regardless of whether the `WHERE` clause of the query is satisfied.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, per documentation:

[Database SQL Language Reference (Oracle 11g): `COALESCE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm)

> Oracle Database uses short-circuit evaluation. The database evaluates each expr value and determines whether it is NULL, rather than evaluating all of the expr values before determining whether any of them is NULL.

Note (having been burned by this myself): be wary of relying on proof-of-concept to determine order-of-operations in SQL language.  SQL is declarative, and the engine is often given the flexibility to execute portions of a statement in arbitrary orders.  So just because one ad-hoc example shows the order of execution of operations A, B, C to be A-then-B-then-C, it may be the case that in different circumstances, engine will opt for alternate execution order, e.g. B-then-A-then-C.

Comment: +1 for your last comment.  There is almost certainly a way to create a SQL statement that will change Oracle from doing what the documentation indicates and what it normally does.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**

```
>select coalesce(1/0,1/0) from dual;
select coalesce(1/0,1/0) from dual
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero


>select coalesce(1,1/0) from dual;

COALESCE(1,1/0)
---------------
              1
```

See [Database SQL Language Reference (Oracle 12c): `COALESCE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions033.htm#SQLRF00617), where it says:

> Oracle Database uses short-circuit evaluation. The database evaluates
>   each expr value and determines whether it is NULL, rather than
>   evaluating all of the expr values before determining whether any of
>   them is NULL.

Answer (score 2):

As written, I would expect it to access the table before it ever evaluates whether the `COALESCE` portion can be short-circuited or not.

Have you tried putting the "hard work" in the place that *can* be short-circuited, with a subquery such as this?

```
SELECT COALESCE(
    IN_ORDER_ID, 
    (SELECT max(order_id) FROM SCHEMA.ORDER WHERE SXC_ORDER_NUMBER = IN_SXC_ORDER_NUMBER)
) INTO V_ORDER_ID from dual;
```